# How to subtract years from a date in a view filter in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, filter, view, date

In SP2013 view filters, if I want to subtract say a week from today I can do `[Today]-7` which works. But I want to remove 30 years, which is `[Today]-10950` however it complains that the date is not in a supported format. It seems to support until 9999.

Also tried `=DATE(YEAR([Today])-30,MONTH([Today]),DAY([Today]))` but same thing.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `TODAY()` function instead? The following returns 6/2/1991.

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-30, MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()))
```

### Update

You could modify your view using SharePoint Designer to set this filter value. It allowed me to set the filter for 30 years in SharePoint 2013 as shown below.

```
<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID"/></OrderBy><Where><Lt><FieldRef Name="DueDate"/>
<Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-10950"/></Value></Lt></Where></Query>
```

Answer (score 0):

TODAY() function is not available in view filter, it just works with calculated column.

So the limit is 9999, we are unable to remove 30 years in view filter.